# Django: Couldn't import JavaScript files from static directory. (Jinja2)

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I just started Django and I'm trying to import JavaScript Files from static directory. So basically I was working on a Flask project for some time, so to import javascript file I was always using - `{{ url_for('.static', filename='js/js_file1.js' }}`. Now I realized that I need to use other methods as - `{% static 'main/js/js_file1.js' %}`. So after some time, I was able to import my css files with - `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'main/css/styles.css' %}">`, they are in `static/main/css/files...`, although my js files are in `static/main/js/files...`. But for some reason, the JavaScript files won't import themselves. I'm importing them with - `<link rel="application/javascript" href="{% static 'main/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}">`.

Here are the network logs from Developer console, as I can see there are no JS files on their way to import themselves.

[image: network_log]

And here are the server Logs from the running server on cmd.
[image: cmd_log]

Developer Console Logs.
[image: Console_log]

My settings.py file has this static_url, which I guess specifies the static folder.

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My whole [HTML File](https://pastebin.com/buBkN1cS).

Answer (score 0):

Firsteval, you have to do `manage.py collectstatic`, then on top of your template you have to import the static files with `{% load static from staticfiles %}`, finally you can import your file `<script src="{% static 'js/myfile.js' %}"></script>`